# Display logo with fixed height and custom width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to setup a Logo with a fixed height and a with not bigger than its container.

So I try something like that :

```
.logo { height:120px; max-width: 100% }
```

But the logo is deformed.

```
.logo { height:120px; max-width: auto }
```

But the logo is bigger than its container.

My bootply : https://www.bootply.com/ogzCKm0Dc3#

Can I achieve something like that without JS or using CSS background-image ?

Comment: i think there is something going wrong with your stylesheet if i add style="height:120px; max-width: 100%;" to the img it works fine in bootply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide max width and height to container then logo will have height and width with respect to container.

Answer (score 0):

Put the width to 100%, and don't put any height or put auto. Then you can change with its container's width as you please.

```css
.logo-container{
width:200px;
}
.logo{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 border">
      <div class="logo-container justify-content-center">
        <img class="logo img-fluid" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/b_rgb:ffffff,c_pad/https://storage.gra1.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_a2570241543b4ca5b4b28bd67d11141a/hopeitup-data/company/cj80c2o9k00gi0lti6b4sulqf">
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div>


<div id="push"></div>
```

By default the image will take the best height for the specific width that you specify.